# How can implement mat like numpy in python can batch operations in Android(Java) ？

Tags: python, java, android, opencv

In python, Numpy arrays can be batched to achieve the following functions: keep those data whose fourth dimension is greater than 0.25

note: item's shape = (6300,7)

```
detects = item[item[..., 4] > 0.25]
```

But in Android, I hava no idea how to implement the above operation, except using a for loop.

Comment: Can you edit question to add [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried and did not work? It will help peope get better idea of what you want to achieve.

Comment: If you're looking for something more functional than a for loop, then you should take a look at the Java Stream API

Comment: @HenryTwist Thanks for your reply. Does this method need to convert opencv mat to java array?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by that. OpenCV doesn't seem to be related to your orignal question!